# Change Visual Studio 2015 code warnings

Tags: coding-style, warnings, visual-studio-2015

Visual studio 2015 creates warnings for things like explicitly specifying internal / private on classes and methods respectively (correctly) stating that the keywords in question are redundant.

Our coding standards require us to specify them explicitly, is there anywhere I can change the settings for these errors so the warnings are not created?

Comment: I'm assuming this is one of those new "light bulb" warnings. If so, you can disable the specific rule in the project properties under code analysis. Edit the current rule set and remove the rule that is causing this. I'm not entirely sure yet which one it is you want though.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can change it according to your needs. It's called **code style** or **coding standard**, it's checked by a **code analysis tool** and it's defined in a **rule set**. You can have a different rule set for each project in your solution.

To assign the rule set to you project(s), open the *Properties* dialog of your solution in the *Solution Explorer* and under *Common Properties* node select *Code Analysis Settings*. You will see a list of all projects inside the solution and you can set a predefined rule set for each one separately. You can try them or check the [Code analysis rule set reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264925.aspx) MSDN article if there is any rule set which fits your needs.

It looks like that the solution properties dialog doesn't allow you to set a custom rule set, so if you need it, open the *Properties* document of a specific project from the *Solution Explorer* and select the *Code Analysis* tab. There is a similar select box for selecting the rule set, but unlike the solution properties, this one allows you to select two more options - *Browse...* and *Choose multiple rule sets...*.

So if none of the predefined rule sets fits your needs, just create your own. You can read for example the [Creating Custom Code Analysis Rule Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380660.aspx) MSDN article to start with the custom code analysis rule set.

Some further reading:

- [Analyzing Application Quality by Using Code Analysis Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264897.aspx)
- [StyleCop vs FxCop: What Is The Difference Between These .NET Code Analysis Tools?](https://www.excella.com/insights/stylecop-vs-fxcop-difference-between-code-analysis-tools)